# Run sleep in background in C language (Linux)

Tags: c, background, sleep, execl

I am trying to call the `sleep` function with '&' in order to run it in thebackground.

The C program is going to replace the Terminal of linux.

The command line in C program (of Linux) has to include an `execl` command, but it is not working.

The command is:

```
execl(path, "sleep", "12&");
```

Path is : "/bin/sleep".

The `execl` runs properly if I don`t writes '&', but if I put '&' the output is:

```
"sleep: invalid time interval ‘12&’
Try 'sleep --help' for more information.".
```

What should I do?
thanks,
Haim

Comment: Could you tell us the purpose of the `sleep` command (i.e., what are you trying to achieve)? There is a POSIX C function called `sleep` that you could use.

Comment: The purpose of sleep is to create a process that works on background, in order to run 'jobs' command later. Jobs command show all background processes. As I said, I am trying to create a personal limited Terminal (Homework).